# How can I hide a photo slideshow until it completely loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I have a Nivo Slider photo slideshow on the index page using Wordpress CMS. I've spent a while optimizing the site (less code, JS at bottom, asyncronous loading, etc.). However, I still have issues with the large photos loading in a sloppy fashion.

Specifically, the photos do not load in the correct order and you can see each photo load. When the slideshow is loading the photos, the last photo loads first then quickly jumps to the first photo when it loads. I'd rather hide the Nivo slideshow until all the photos load (there are only 4 at the most).

We are using jQuery as our JS library and it loads in wp_head. What code can I use to delay showing this slideshow, or is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: use the lowest resolution photos possible for fast loading.

Comment: I don't have direct control of the photos sadly. Each photo is coming in around 70kb and has a resolution of 900x410 and they are very color rich.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$(document).ready( /*...*/ );` to trigger the slideshow, use `$(window).load( /*...*/)`, to launch the slideshow when the images have finished loading.

I'd also suggest hiding the slideshow images with css, and then only un-hiding them in the `$(window).load()` event.

Comment: So the first line reads jQuery(document).ready(function($) { and you propose it be changed to jQuery(window).load(function($) {? Is this syntax correct?

Comment: @Micah, yep: that's exactly it =)

Comment: Hmm, okay. I have the script loading directly below wp_head but it doesn't seem to affect the way the slideshow loads. I still see each individual photo load in real-time instead of just showing everything after the images are loaded.

Comment: It appears Nivo has a built-in loading.gif that I am using. I just set the bg color to match the surrounding div so that it matched and that seemed to hide the loading until everything was loaded. Sadly, however, I was not able to properly use $(window).load() with this website. Firebug threw an error that said it was not a valid function. Dunno why that is.